# getting reference to a input element inside a custom component in angular?

Tags: angular

I just noticed that if I have an instance of a component, for example, MyInput. In another component, I can use ViewChild to get a reference to MyInput but I cannot see the input without then further exposing it from the MyInput component.

```
//my-input.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-input',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" [id]="id" [name]="name">
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyInputComponent {
  @Input()
  name = null;
  
  @Input()
  id = null;
}
```

```
//my-container.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-input',
  template: `
    <app-my-input #name id="name" name="name"></app-my-input>
    <app-my-input #message id="message" name="message"></app-my-input>
  `
})
export class MyContaineromponent {
 //this works and I get the instance of MyInputComponent. But how can I get the dom ref to the input so I can query the value??
 @ViewChild('message') message:ComponentRef<MyInputComponent>;
 @ViewChild('name') name:ComponentRef<MyInputComponent>;
}
```

Given the example above, although I get access to the `componentRefs` I need access to the dom, preferably without needing to expose another ref from the  MyInputComponent. Any ideas about what am I missing here?

Comment: Try this @ViewChild('message', {read: ElementRef}) message: ElementRef; Then you can get access to native element by doing message.nativeElement;

Comment: thanks, that works but only if I use a templateRef, I could not make it work with the id selector for example. But it is good enough , if you put it in an answer I can accept that. But any ideas how to do the same but using a the id as selector and any ways I can get access directly to the input instead?

Comment: You rigth, my bad. I cannot edit my previous message. Its ok. I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Components are designed to be close to modifications, you won't be able to query the template of a child component. What do you to do with reference to the input ?

Comment: not sure what you mean, the example Bruno gave actually works. I am not trying to modify anything. But if renders to the DOM you can modify anything even in angular. regardless the point is learning. I understand how components should work. but I am actually trying to understand why it is not possible to get a reference by id and then reading the value when I need to query it. The example from Bruno not only requires a template ref in each component, but also I need to queryselector it afterviewInit for example

Comment: You can't do @ViewChild('yourElementId') because htlm attributes are not supported selectors, that's how @ViewChild is designed. Read https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description to see the supported selectors.

Comment: I see, I suspected but I did not understand the docs at all. Anything else I can do that achieve that just querying the dom at runtime, but from angular api instead of getting a ref and then using nativeElement.querySelector anyways?

Comment: could you write down what would you expect in code for handling the DOM element? I don't quite understand what you say "I cannot see the input without then further exposing it from the MyInput component." or "I need access to the dom, preferably without needing to expose another ref from the MyInputComponent"

Comment: @Andres2142 https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-notxqv?file=my-select.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, you will need to have a local reference to any custom component you create or HTML element in order to handle whatever you need, unless you listen for a particular event for that element, given your example for `MyInputComponent`, it could be like the following:

```html
<input type="text" [id]="id" [name]="name" (input)="onInput($event)">
```

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyInputComponent {
  // ...
  // ...
  @Output() input = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onInput(event: Event): void {
    const value = ((event.target) as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.input.emit(value);
  }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```html
<app-my-input (input)="onTextEntered($event)"></app-my-input>
```

```js
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent {
  onTextEntered(value: string): void {
    console.log('The value: ', value);
  }
}
```

In this particular case, without having to use a `#localReference` or using `ViewChild`, the parent component has access to `MyInputComponent` value.

There is another way without using `ViewChild` or listening to a specific event, but you have to have a local reference to the element, given your stackblitz example with the `select`, it could be like the following:

```html
<div>
      <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
      <select name="cars" id="cars" (change)="onChange($event)">
        <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

```js
@Component({...})
export class MySelectComponent {
  selectedValue = 'volvo';

  onChange(event: Event): void {
    const value = ((event.target) as HTMLSelectElement).value;
    this.selectedValue = value;
  }
}
```

**Parent Component**

```html
<my-select #selectRef></my-select>

<button (click)="getValue(selectRef.selectedValue)">Get Select Value</button>
```

```
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent {
  getValue(value: string): void {
    console.log('value: ', value);
  }
}
```

Here, having the local reference to `my-select` I could access the `public` class property of `selectedValue` and grab the value of it from outside without `ViewChild`, and you could access everything from that component as long as you have `public` class properties or functions.

Comment: you are relying on the fact that I can go and change the MyComponentInput. which I should not be able to. Easiest way I found is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016018/4475288 where you can get a reference to the entire element and from there you can query anything with a single ref.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify in your question if you are able to modify the desired `component` or not. The use of the `directive` seems to me a valid approach. Good luck

Comment: Right, I should have been more explicit about it. That is I meantioned without exposing into from within the component. But that can mean different things.